# Appium inspector fails with following error: Failed to create session. An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original e

Tags: appium-ios

Setup

- Macbook air m1
- Appium via npm v1.22.3
- Appium Desktop v1.22.3-4
- Replaced webdriveragent from https://github.com/appium/WebDriverAgent/releases/tag/v4.9.0
- Appium Inspector https://github.com/appium/appium-inspector/releases

When I start appium server via command line or gui, I get the same error. I cannot run appium automated tests on iOS because of this error.

Capabilities

```
{
  "appium:deviceName": "iPhone SE",
  "platformName": "iOS",
  "appium:platformVersion": "16.1",
  "appium:automationName": "XCUITest",
  "appium:udid": "00008030-001939C20207802E",
  "appium:app": "/app.ipa",
  "appium:bundleId": "com.iphone.Skull-iQ.dev",
  "appium:xcodeSigningId": "iPhone Developer",
  "appium:xcodeOrgId": "XXXX"
}
```

Applium log

```
umanga.madawala@MBWS31 appium-webdriveragent % appium
[Appium] Welcome to Appium v1.22.3
[Appium] Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session
[HTTP] {"capabilities":{"alwaysMatch":{"appium:deviceName":"iPhone SE","platformName":"iOS","appium:platformVersion":"16.1","appium:automationName":"XCUITest","appium:udid":"00008030-001939C20207802E","appium:app":"/Users/umanga.madawala/Desktop/Skull-iQ App/Skull-IQ Dev 2022-11-24 09-20-38/Apps/Skull-iQ-Dev.ipa","appium:bundleId":"com.iphone.Skull-iQ.dev","appium:xcodeSigningId":"iPhone Developer","appium:xcodeOrgId":"AB3DZ8D7X2","appium:includeSafariInWebviews":true,"appium:newCommandTimeout":3600,"appium:connectHardwareKeyboard":true},"firstMatch":[{}]},"desiredCapabilities":{"appium:deviceName":"iPhone SE","platformName":"iOS","appium:platformVersion":"16.1","appium:automationName":"XCUITest","appium:udid":"00008030-001939C20207802E","appium:app":"/Users/umanga.madawala/Desktop/Skull-iQ App/Skull-IQ Dev 2022-11-24 09-20-38/Apps/Skull-iQ-Dev.ipa","appium:bundleId":"com.iphone.Skull-iQ.dev","appium:xcodeSigningId":"iPhone Developer","appium:xcodeOrgId":"AB3DZ8D7X2","appium:includeSafariInWebviews":true,"appium:...
[debug] [W3C] Calling AppiumDriver.createSession() with args: [{"appium:deviceName":"iPhone SE","platformName":"iOS","appium:platformVersion":"16.1","appium:automationName":"XCUITest","appium:udid":"00008030-001939C20207802E","appium:app":"/Users/umanga.madawala/Desktop/Skull-iQ App/Skull-IQ Dev 2022-11-24 09-20-38/Apps/Skull-iQ-Dev.ipa","appium:bundleId":"com.iphone.Skull-iQ.dev","appium:xcodeSigningId":"iPhone Developer","appium:xcodeOrgId":"AB3DZ8D7X2","appium:includeSafariInWebviews":true,"appium:newCommandTimeout":3600,"appium:connectHardwareKeyboard":true},null,{"alwaysMatch":{"appium:deviceName":"iPhone SE","platformName":"iOS","appium:platformVersion":"16.1","appium:automationName":"XCUITest","appium:udid":"00008030-001939C20207802E","appium:app":"/Users/umanga.madawala/Desktop/Skull-iQ App/Skull-IQ Dev 2022-11-24 09-20-38/Apps/Skull-iQ-Dev.ipa","appium:bundleId":"com.iphone.Skull-iQ.dev","appium:xcodeSigningId":"iPhone Developer","appium:xcodeOrgId":"AB3DZ8D7X2","appium:includeSafariInWebviews":true,"appium:newCommandTimeout":3600,"appium:connectHardwareKeyb...
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event 'newSessionRequested' logged at 1669328866809 (23:27:46 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time))
[debug] [Appium] /opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-webdriveragent/index.js:1
[debug] [Appium] import * as dependencies from './lib/check-dependencies';
[debug] [Appium] ^^^^^^
[debug] [Appium] 
[debug] [Appium] SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
[debug] [Appium]     at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:74:18)
[debug] [Appium]     at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1128:20)
[debug] [Appium]     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1169:27)
[debug] [Appium]     at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1259:10)
[debug] [Appium]     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1068:32)
[debug] [Appium]     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:909:12)
[debug] [Appium]     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1092:19)
[debug] [Appium]     at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
[debug] [Appium]     at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/lib/driver.js:5:1)
[debug] [Appium]     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1205:14)
[debug] [Appium]     at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1259:10)
[debug] [Appium]     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1068:32)
[debug] [Appium]     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:909:12)
[debug] [Appium]     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1092:19)
[debug] [Appium]     at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
[debug] [Appium]     at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/index.js:4:1)
(node:945) [DEP0128] DeprecationWarning: Invalid 'main' field in '/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-webdriveragent/package.json' of './build/index.js'. Please either fix that or report it to the module author
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event 'newSessionStarted' logged at 1669328866836 (23:27:46 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time))
[debug] [W3C] Encountered internal error running command: Error: Could not load a driver for automationName 'XCUITest' and platformName 'iOS'. Please verify your Appium installation
[debug] [W3C]     at AppiumDriver.getDriverAndVersionForCaps (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/appium/lib/appium.js:268:11)
[debug] [W3C]     at AppiumDriver.createSession (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/appium/lib/appium.js:340:66)
[debug] [W3C]     at commandExecutor (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-base-driver/lib/basedriver/driver.js:335:9)
[debug] [W3C]     at AppiumDriver.executeCommand (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-base-driver/lib/basedriver/driver.js:349:15)
[debug] [W3C]     at AppiumDriver.executeCommand (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/appium/lib/appium.js:549:26)
[debug] [W3C]     at asyncHandler (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-base-driver/lib/protocol/protocol.js:297:34)
[debug] [W3C]     at /opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-base-driver/lib/protocol/protocol.js:423:15
[debug] [W3C]     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
[debug] [W3C]     at next (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
[debug] [W3C]     at Route.dispatch (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
[debug] [W3C]     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
[debug] [W3C]     at /opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
[debug] [W3C]     at Function.process_params (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
[debug] [W3C]     at next (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
[debug] [W3C]     at logger (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/morgan/index.js:144:5)
[debug] [W3C]     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 43 ms - 735
```

Comment: Why did you replace the webdriver? Does it work when you don't?

Comment: no. it returns Cannot link directly with dylib/framework, your binary is not an allowed client of /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/
Contents/Developer/Platforms/AppleTOS.platform/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/
XCTAutomationSupport. framework/XCTAutomation Support for architecture arm64 error.
I resolved it by upgrading to appium 2.0 beta. :)